# JMeter non-GUI mode taking longer than expected with minimal load

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am running JMeter in non-GUI mode for load testing a single API with just one thread, but I'm experiencing longer execution times than anticipated. The test plan is simple, yet the execution is significantly slower than when running in GUI mode. GUI finishes within seconds, but non-GUI takes hours, Here are the details:

1. Test plan consists of a single API request and one thread in the thread group.
2. I'm using the command `jmeter -n -t ./plan.jmx -l ./jfs/results.jtl` to execute the test plan in non-GUI mode.
3. The API response time is acceptable when tested manually or using JMeter in GUI mode.
4. I've already checked for common issues like resource allocation, ramp-up time, iterations, and server response time, but they don't seem to be the cause.
5. There are no listeners or additional plugins in the test plan that could slow down the execution.
6. I've verified that the JMX file used is the same in both GUI and non-GUI modes.

I'm wondering if there are any specific considerations or configurations I might be missing when running JMeter in non-GUI mode that could explain the difference in execution time. Are there any known limitations or factors that could impact the performance of JMeter in non-GUI mode? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're facing [JMeter issue 6008](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues/6008), the options are in:

1. Insert  `<boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>` line into the [.jmx script directly](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)
2. Downgrade to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)
3. Upgrade to [JMeter Nightly build](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html)
4. Wait for next JMeter release 5.6.1 which presumably will contain the fix
5. Switch to another Thread Group like [Open Model Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group)